# Connect Node-RED to a RabbitMQ Priority Queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, node-red

I have a RabbitMQ queue that is declared with the following options:

```
{
    "queue": "events/online",
    "durable": true,
    "args": {
        "x-max-priority": 10
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect to the queue from Node-RED, using the `node-red-contrib-amqp` plugin, with the following Topology that is set under the connection source:

```
{
    "queues": [
        {
            "name": "events/online",
            "durable": true,
            "options": {
                "x-max-priority": 10
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> "AMQP input node disconnect error: Operation failed: QueueDeclare; 406
>   (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent
>   arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'myqueue' in vhost 'vhost': received
>   none but current is the value '10' of type 'signedint'""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is as follows.

Make sure the following checkbox is selected: `"use AMQP topology definition (JSON) defined below"`

```
{
    "queues": [
        {
            "name": "events/online",
            "durable": true,
            "options": {
                "maxPriority": 10
            }
        }
    ]
}
```